# Service Browser for Zend AMF

Tags: php, apache-flex, amfphp, zend-amf

I have some questions:

1. Does Zend AMF has a service browser feature like AMFPHP does? Some people do mention about [zamfbrowser](http://www.zamfbrowser.org/), but at the time I'm posting this question, the site is still unavailable.
2. Is there any possibility to use AMFPHP's service browser with Zend AMF?

Thanks in advance!
Regards, Andree.

Comment: *(reference)* http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Amf/Server/Zend_Amf_Server.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the ZamfBrowswer does just that - http://zamfbrowser.riaforge.org/index.cfm

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com

Comment: Ah, okay ! The download link in that site is not working in firefox, so I thought the link is broken. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMFPHP with Zend_AMF.  I show you how here: http://wesleyalmeida.net/what-ive-learned/how-to-give-zend_amf-a-service-browser-using-amfphp/